# Bit confused on derivative in dynamical system

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hi I am confused on the following.

( Let $x'=dx/dt$)

My teacher said,

If for example we have $x'=\sin x$,then find $x''$. So initially I thought well isn't that just $\cos x$, but that answer is $\cos x\sin x$. So I am confused on what variable are being integrated and when. Ie, why is $d/dt \sin x \neq \cos x$?

I also do know the chain rule but I'm not sure where it is being applied.
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to recall the chain rule.

$${dx'\over dt} = {dx'\over dx}\cdot {dx\over dt}=\cos x\cdot x' = \cos x\sin x$$

The trick is to remember that the prime means "derivative with respect to $t$" not "derivative with respect to $x$." The notation is just a bit confusing.

Comment: but isn't my sinx just defined in terms of the x?

Comment: or is it really sin(x(t))?

Comment: @PersonaA yes, secretly $x=x(t)$, we just are suppressing this in the notation because it's harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You're derivating on $t$, not $x$. It's not explicitely written, but you can guess it because you're computing $x'$ (this could not exist if you would derive on $x$).
Since you're derivating on $t$, you can assume that $x$ is a function of $t$: $x = x(t)$. (otherwise deriving by $t$ would give $0$, not very interesting)

Then, you can just apply the chain rule.